# Так ли нужна "ИТишнику" ученая степень?

Tags: работа

Собственно вопрос прост и сложен одновременно: как вы считаете, насколько нужна "ИТишнику" ученая степень?
Закончил факультет математики и информатики в [Таврическом национальном университете имени В.И. Вернадского](http://www.tnu.crimea.ua/)

Получил магистра информатики. Специальность программист-математик, преподаватель-математики. Диплом, нужно сказать, везде котируется.

Академическую работу, нужно признаться, у нас превратили в черт знает что. А украинскому государству, Наука как таковая не нужна вовсе.

В раздумьях, что в дальнейшем может дать ученая степень PhD...

Comment: главное чтоб ученая степень будущего начальника была не ниже =)

Comment: Шутка юмора - всегда хорошо. Правда, в каждой шутке есть доля шутки)

Comment: >А украинскому государству, Наука как таковая не нужна вовсе

к сожалению, вы, братья-славяне, не одиноки - у нас, в России, академическая наука  тоже не особо котируется, несмотря на все эти басни про Сколково-Распилково

Comment: Хм. Ну вот у нас в компании ученая степень дает прибавку к зарплате

Comment: Вам везет)

Comment: @МастерДобрыхДел, в добавках за звания ничего хорошего нет.

IMHO ученая степень должна получаться *естественным* образом. 

(конечно, это в  идеале, в реальной жизни процесс другой.)


Например, Вам *действительно интересна* какая-то область исследований. Вы хотите поглубже в ней разобраться и поступаете в аспирантуру. Там учитесь и выполняете некие разработки. Если получаете нетривиальный результат, то оформляете его и получаете степень.

Еще один вариант (уже ближе к жизни, но редок) - по совокупности работ. Это когда Вы диссерт не пишите, а просто все признали Ваш вклад.

Comment: @avp, по совокупности сейчас степень практически не присуждают. 

А по поводу добавок к зарплате - не согласен, как работающий в сфере науки. В нашей стране такие низкие зарплаты у ученых, что добавка за степень (тоже в общем копеечная) уже неплохое подспорье и какая-то даже моральная поддержка.

Comment: @DreamChild, все, что власть придержащие говорят о поддержке науки и т.д.,- вранье бессовестное. Все делается, чтобы науку добить окончательно.

Comment: @mikillskegg, ну, жизнь есть жизнь, в идеальные схемы она никогда не укладывалась. Даже когда по совокупности давали. 

Про моральный же фактор добавки - абсолютно согласен.

--

Но неужели, сейчас, основной доход в науке это зарплата и надбавки?

Или все-таки (если честно) основная часть это более-менее "левые" темы (я имею в виду сторонние разработки, консультации, проекты в рабочее время и на "казенном" оборудовании, а не махинации с бюджетом), но попасть в них можно только из определенного круга?

Comment: @avp, все очень по-разному. Но многие сидят на чистом окладе. В том числе очень достойные люди и хорошие специалисты.

Comment: Я думаю примерно так - всем до тимлидера включительно, вышка вообще не нужна, хватит колледжа (пту). Ведь вы же не считаете что бригадиру на заводе нужна вышка (хотя и бывает конечно). А ученая степень может быть нужна архитекторам стандартизаторам и прочим подобным.

Comment: А вы не считаете, что современному человеку, буде он бригадир, водопроводчик или тимлидер, нужно высшее образование

Comment: @regenerator нет не считаю, это лишнее. Надо нормальное проф образование, а не массовое высшее.

Comment: @Vfvtnjd, о чем именно Вы? Уточните. Прислать Вам резюме; список проектов; дипломную работу?

Answer (score 16):

Вообще то корочка бывает двух типов - собственно бумажка и знания, которые есть в голове. Очень редко бывает, что одно соответствует другому. Я встречал много умных людей, которым не нужна крутая бумажка. Они и так имеют хорошую работу. И встречал людей с докторскими бумажками, но знаний было по нулям.

Исходя из этого. Крутая бумажка возможно поможет в первые несколько дней, если устроитесь на работу. А дальше нужны будут знания. Знания эквивалентные Высшему образованию программисту нужны. А вот корочка... разве что упростить некоторые государственные двери.

Comment: Согласен со всеми пунктами. Всегда придерживался мнения, что важнее, что человек реально умеет, а не конкретно его количество корочек на полке и дипломов/сертификатов на стене.

Только пару уточнений:
1. Речь идет не о Высшем образовании, а о Postgraduate, кандидатской работе и получении степени PhD ()
2. Знания, полученные в процессе исследования, написания диссертации и ее защиты, как правило, чисто теоретические (!). И мало применимы в дальнейшей работе.

В моей ситуации они вдвойне мало применимы, т.к. специальность "Теоретическая информатика и кибернетика".

Comment: Будут проверять соответсвие умений и описанных в резюме освоенных технологий. Наличие Вашего статуса даст хорошую рекомендацию в любом случае

Comment: Знакомые рассказывали, что работодатели на "корочку" из перехода тоже ведутся :) Никто же не будет проверять, учился ты или нет.

Comment: Навального вроде хотели проверить, но это уже совсем другая история)

Comment: @lampa, в серьезных компаниях проверяют.

Comment: почти согласен с @KoVadim, хотя личный опыт показывает что есть основные (имхо) критерия которые можно использовать для "измерения" качества работника:

    1) наличие бумажки
    2) наличие знаний
    3) наличие опыта
    4) наличие желания (отношение к работе, наим)

вот соотношение этих характеристик как раз определяет каждого человека как работника

Answer (score 9):

Спрашивается: нужна для чего?

Если для того, чтобы стать классным специалистом в прикладном программировании и делать карьеру в крупных компаниях, то не обязательно. Просто ВО вполне достаточно. Хотя в иных случаях степень может помочь с трудоустройстом. Был у меня знакомый инженер-авиационщик, даже не программист и не математик. Но после получения им степени канд. технаук его сразу взяли программистом в Шереметьево, почти вне конкурса. Дальше ему, конечно, пришлось очень много чего осваивать. Так что степень не помешает, но особой необходимости в ней нет.

Если хотите делать именно академическую карьеру, заниматься наукой, если у Вас есть такие возможности и желание, то тут степень необходима.

Далее решайте сами.

Answer (score 2):

Математикам почет и уважение! Особенно тем, кто на переднем крае Науки. Не помешает математика, конечно. А иногда очень даже сильно поможет. Например, знание λ-исчислени в программировании на Хаскелле (даже имеется около 8 вакансий на должность Хаскелл-программиста). Другой вопрос, что мышление математика и мышление программиста не одно и тоже, математик чаще нацелен на решение задачи, а программист на поиск алгоритма решения задачи. Математик больше сконцентрирован, а программист более ленив, ибо задачу решит компьютер. Математик более строг в рассуждениях, программист больше (чем математик) доверяет интуиции (иногда даже слишком), а языку программирования чаще всего не хватает выразительных возможностей для строгого доказательства корректности кода.

Comment: Быть ленивым, это не обязательное качество программиста. Он может быть трудолюбив, его изыскания в упрощении могут быть основаны не на лени, а на желании оптимизировать, ускорить.

Comment: собственно, из вышесказанного вытекает нижеследующее - хороший математический базис нужен программисту хотя бы для самоорганизации - всяческого рода матан способен хорошо упорядочивать мозги

Comment: лень двигатель прогресса, как известно. да, матан улучшает мозг программиста, но и обратное верно - программирование полезно математику ИМХО

Answer (score 1):

Начал читать вопрос, думал, что опять вопрос в стиле, нужно ли ВО программисту:) 
Мне кажется, это сыграет роль, но только в больших компаниях. Будет конкурс на должность какую-то, может сыграть, конечно при прочих равных у вас с оппонентами аргументах.

Comment: Тут даже скорее не вопрос, а обсуждение с комментариями.
Необходимость ВО, его качество и содержание - вообще отдельный больной вопрос для стран СНГ.

ВО нужно почти любому современному человеку (программисту в том числе))), если оно не идет в ущерб реально полезным, практическим знаниям, опыту, умениям и пр. Ну и здоровью в конце концов...

Comment: Здоровье подсаживается(о наболевшем: есть день и 3 лекции в нем ~ 5 часов сидеть - это возможно,но нужны нормальные стулья, как это оборудуется на работе). Для других знаний вроде ущерба нет, если учеба не совсем убивает личное время. А по сути вопроса, чтобы извлечь бОльшую пользу от этого статуса, нужна именно крупная компаня. Всем будет приятно иметь такого сотрудника у себя, но доплачивать(и учитывать) будут готовы только крупные игроки. Это мое субьективное мнение, могу ошибаться:)

Answer (score 0):

Сижу изучаю программирование от триггеров до нейронных сетей... сижу себе тихо изучаю ченить делаю.... а потом оглянулся, а оказывается люди с ученой степенью подходят и совета спрашивают.... Вот думаю пойду открою фирму на жену и буду скайнет строить....

Comment: Тригиров? Ну-ну. Значит изучать есть еще много что =)

Comment: "Чем больше изучаешь, тем меньше ты знаешь"© Сейчас заинтересовался Эфирным ветром.. тема интереснейшая советую. А чем больше загадок мы изучаем, действительно, тем больше вопросов в ответ получаем. :-]

Comment: @Bimawa

> "Чем больше изучаешь, тем меньше ты знаешь" 

вы неправильно написали..., **Чем больше изучаешь, тем больше ты не знаешь**, т.к. изучение не уменьшает кол-во знаний, а увеличивает границы "незнания".